# jQuery re-set functions after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

I have some issues with .load :

My site use this line of code to toggle a button:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
// my button function
});
```

I've write some little ajax call to load the div without reload, but the button action is not set:

```
$("#ajax-load").load('/ #content',function(){
    $('#ajax-load .button').click(function(){
    // my button function
    });
});
```

This doesn't works, the content shows correctly, but the JS functions in refreshed content not.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$('#ajax-load').on('click','.button',function(){
    // my button function
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Should note this is for jQuery 1.7+ only

Comment: @MikeRobinson  Possibly, but the jQuery docs did that for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use [jQuery.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)? `live` will associate the actions with all existing and future occurrences of your selector. So if you have:

```
$('.button').live('click', function(){ });
```

This should work with the existing `.button` elements and future ones.

**Edit:** in jQuery 1.7 you should use [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `live`.

Comment: blah blah [.live is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/) blah blah [use .on instead](http://api.jquery.com/on/) blah blah.

Comment: Even in jQuery < 1.7 you should never use `.live()` but `.delegate()`. Unless you have a very old jquery which doesn't support `.delegate()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery < 1.7 use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) otherwise use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

You should [not use live](http://jsperf.com/jquery-live-vs-delegate-vs-on).